# How to move rows in between tabs on Check True

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

### Move Rows on checkbox

I need to move rows to another tab on checkbox = TRUE, but the following code is crashing, my sheet as it is terribly slow. How can I make it faster?

#### Updated

How can I check for boxes = true across the whole document without using a for loop and without crashing the sheet?

| Check | ID | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ☑ | 1 | 3456 |
| ☑ | 2 | TOPRPR |
| [] | 3 | AZECRT |

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "main" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Completed" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("discart");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the event object more intelligently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "main" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if(sh.getName() == "Completed" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("discart");
    let trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not move the rows from Main to Completed tab

Comment: try it now.....

Comment: How can I check for boxes = true across the whole document without using a for loop and without crashing the sheet?

Comment: Most likely whatever method you chose will use a loop internally so what's the issue with loops.

Comment: I just worry about folding into multiple loops and making the whole sheet unresponsive. Is it also a way to cache the sheet?

Comment: That's unlikely since simple trigger will timeout after 30 seconds.